# Font Book says multiple copies are installed

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I downloaded a free font that included four `.ttf` files for the Regular, Italic, Bold, and Bold Italic variants, all different. I dragged them into Font Book and they all appeared in a group, but the three variants other than Regular were flagged as duplicates:

> Multiple copies of this font are installed.

If I choose `Resolve automatically` all variants except Regular are shown as `Off`. If I right-click and enable these variants, ignoring the multiple-copies message, I'm still not able to use all the variants in TextEdit or Photoshop (the only apps I've checked in so far).

What's going on with this font? The previews in Font Book look exactly as I expect them to (rendering as the proper variants).

Answer (score 1):

Have you, first of all, looked in /System/Library/Fonts, in /Library/Fonts, and in ~/Library/Fonts to see what actually exists ... as opposed to depending on software to tell you.

I expect that both Photoshop and TextEdit fonts behaving properly depends on the Mac default fonts - and fonts commonly used by those (and other) apps - being in the correct location.

Comment: I had compared /Library/Fonts to ~/Library/Fonts, but hadn't checked /System/Library/Fonts — just checked there too — but the font files only exist in ~/Library/Fonts. Other fonts in that folder do appear in Photoshop with all the variants working. I was expecting this might be something amiss with the metadata in this particular font, but that's a pretty random, uneducated hunch at this point.

Comment: @RwwL, when I read the post, I thought of the metadata first as well. I suspect that one of the names that OS X uses is the same across all the fonts.

Comment: @RwwL Can you remember the source of where you downloaded these font files so I can try to reproduce and then diagnose the problem? If it fails on multiple machines, then it might be related to improper metadata naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I snagged it from here: http://www.ffonts.net/Dreamspeak-Bold.font

Comment: Watch out for the awful, awful ads on that page throwing up fake download buttons for who-knows-what, though.

Comment: i should have added, check on the default fonts for your system, be sure no others are in that folder, and remove any not in the list. Delete - by hand is fine, or move to your user fonts.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like your Apple devices are impacted by the **SIP**.

> **were flagged as duplicates**

Our Macs, identical and eventually worse. All those `verify` and `resolve automatically` methods, useless. Our windows devices suffer the **VSS**, ugly (don't ask)! Your SIP situation unattended will worsen, in part reappearing across macOS reinstallation, as remembered system behaviors are. You can improve your macOS performance, remove the aberrant system behaviors. You need pencil, paper, and a few minutes to run some commands in sequence. Safe boot to Terminal, then...

```
    *csrutil disable*
```

then

```
    *sudo chflags norestricted /usr/local && sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local*
```

then

```
    *bash/bin/usr netboot add n.n.n.n*
```

n = whatever your local network uses (e.g., 10.0.0.1) ~ then use other commands to secure NetTools and Github as per [Adding Another Layer](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/) with [That HUGE Manatee](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/10/01/how-i-got-el-capitain-working-with-my-developer-tools/).

Hope this helps. *Btw !!* App Store item to manage SIP, **easily**?

***SIP's*** are great for baby-sitting. Hopeless for getting the job done. Not funny!

Comment: I think I'd want to verify that SIP was the culprit before disabling it. The OP installed their new fonts to `~/Library/Fonts`, not `/System/Library/Fonts`, so I'm not seeing an obvious connection with SIP.